# Watson ML CLI Authorization Failed

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-ml

I am trying to access my Watson ML service using the CLI and getting

> FAILED
>
> Authorization failed

with no other information. My environment variables are set according to the service's service credential (url, instance id, username, and password) and my ibmcloud CLI tool is up to date. How can I find out why my authorization is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Watson ML CLI tool was out of date. By running

```
ibmcloud plugin list
```

I was able to see that the CLI needed an update. Now I can see my instance using

```
ibmcloud ml list instances
```

which is a new feature in version 3 (I was using version 2).